# get value in the same table by index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have Structure Like This Picture

[image]

How To Get Value Of `datte` Column BY value of `ke` column

I Want To Use Function `DATEDIFF` at column `DATTE`

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: You should take a SQL tutorial first

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: So for every NAME you always have 2 rows with KE = 1,2. KE = 1 means start_date, and KE = 2 means finesh_date and you want to calculate detediff between these 2 dates for evey NAME?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (KE int, name varchar(100), datte date);
insert into @t values 
(1, 'CAT1', '20170101'), (2, 'CAT1', '20170102'), 
(1, 'CAT2', '20170201'), (2, 'CAT2', '20170215'), 
(1, 'CAT3', '20170112');

with cte as
(
select 
       name,
       max(case ke when 1 then datte end) as start_dt,
       max(case ke when 2 then datte end) as finish_dt
from @t 
group by name
)

select *, datediff(day, start_dt, finish_dt) as days
from cte;
```